# Raspberry Pi expansion board for measuring and data logging wishlist

Tags: hardware

Im working on new version of my Raspberry Pi expansion board.

My previous board (actually it was a prototype) was designed to measure and log voltage, current, power and light intensity for whole year or more.

Here is what I have in old version:

- 4 channel high accurracy ADC converter for voltage/current/power measurements
- realtime clock supported in Linux
- IR receiver for remote control
- whole board fits many standard Pi casings

Here is what I want in new version:

- HD44780 display connector
- rotary encoder/4 buttons connector
- few LED's

I realized that I have some space left on PCB.

**What else I can add to make it more versatile/useful?**

Requirements:

- space-saving (i have no space for things big like relays)
- not expensive

Comment: what is your problem and/or question? I could not even find a question mark "?" in your "question".

Comment: @lenik Now better?

Answer (score 2):

Just some thoughts based on my experience with Pis and professional loggers...

- **More GPIO.** It gives you far more additional options for connecting other devices later on, or for control of measuring devices. There are I2C and SPI multiplexers that would let you do this.
- **More Analog I/O.** You've got 4 channels, but another 4 or even 8 would be great. If you want to connect a full bridge sensor, you need to measure two voltage levels, which means you could only connect two. That capability is often what separates low-end and high-end data loggers.
- **Serial (RS/232).** - Occasionally you'll come across some random bit of kit you'd really like to log that uses a serial port. The Pi has one on board but it's stuck at TTL levels. A MAX232 adapter in there would be great. Additional ports would be nice, but probably not a high priority. I think I've in total come across only about 3 things that would really need the serial.
- **Battery backup.** One of the most annoying things about data logging is what you end up *not* data logging because the power has gone out for a short blip. A sort of UPS type feature with an embedded Li-ION battery would at least let the system shut down cleanly. If you could somehow get it to trigger itself back on that'd be really nice too.

Comment: I thought serial port today is obsolete. I use USB and FT232 chip in my microcontroller projects.

Comment: My ADC unfortunately is not suitable for fast measurements (like bridge sensing). Im using full differential 4SPS@18bit ADC (240SPS@12bit), because it's pretty cheap, it has good built-in voltage reference.

Comment: I've recently come across RS-232 for a particle counter and then again for an load cell system. Both were to be used in a data logging capacity. Maybe add a second, faster, lower resolution ADC then?

Comment: Now im seriously thinking about adding PIC/AVR microcontroller and piece of "universal PCB pattern". 40 pin PIC can have 16 ADC channels, DAC, PWM and a lot of extra IO.